# Conditional update in pandas dataframe column based on paragraph type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
 data = {
    'document_section_id': ['1', '1.1', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '3', None, None, None, '4.1', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '1.2', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '1.3', '1.3.1', None, None, '1.3.2', None, None, None, None, '1.3.3', None, None, None, '1.3.4', None, None,None],
    '   ': ['Heading1', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'TblFootnote', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'TblFootnote', 'Heading3', 'Heading3', 'Heading3', 'Heading1']
}
```

I want to do the below:

1. get all rows spanning from one occurrence of "`Heading1`" to the next occurrence of "`Heading1`" in the "`paragraph_type`" column.
2. Capture and store the "`SECTION_ID`" value corresponding to the first occurrence of "`Heading1`" in a variable called `var1`.
3. In this specified range (Heading1-Heading1), if the value of any section_id column does not begin with the value stored in var1, then replace its "SECTION_ID" with an empty string. Ex: for 10th and 14th row section id doesnt starts with 1 so update the value with ''

This has to be done for all existing Heading1

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
modified_dfs = []
for i in range(len(df[df['PARAGRAPH_TYPE'] == 'Heading1']) - 1):
    start_index = df[df['PARAGRAPH_TYPE'] == 'Heading1'].index[i]
    end_index = df[df['PARAGRAPH_TYPE'] == 'Heading1'].index[i+1]
    var1 = df.loc[start_index, 'SECTION_ID']

    section_df = df.reset_index().loc[start_index:end_index-1].copy()

    for j in range(start_index, end_index):
        SECTION_ID = section_df.loc[j, 'SECTION_ID']
        if isinstance(SECTION_ID, str) and not SECTION_ID.startswith(str(var1)):
            section_df.loc[j, 'SECTION_ID'] = ''

    modified_dfs.append(section_df)

result_df = pd.concat(modified_dfs)
```

expected output:

```
    output = {
    'document_section_id': ['1', '1.1', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '', None, None, None, '', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '1.2', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '1.3', '1.3.1', None, None, '1.3.2', None, None, None, None, '1.3.3', None, None, None, '1.3.4', None, None, None, None],
    ' ': ['Heading1', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'TblFootnote', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'ListParagraph', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'TblFootnote', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'Heading3', 'TblFootnote', 'Heading3', 'Heading3', 'Heading3', 'Heading1']
}
```

Comment: your third point is lil confusion , can you please elaborate? and your dataframe length is not same for both columns.

Comment: Your input seems invalid, please double check

Comment: Invalid in the sense? I just now tried creating a python dict and it worked

Comment: edited the format. can you please check now?

Comment: "*ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length*", one list has 52 items, the other 53

Comment: The output is still invalid. Please double check everything when posting a question, this avoid wasting ereryone's time, downvotes and closed questions.

Comment: @mozway Sorry, my bad, the `"}"` was missing. Please check now.

Comment: The **output** is invalid. Different lengths again

Comment: You can ignore the output. basically 3 and 4.1 needs to be replaced with ". anyway have changed the output

Comment: There is still a None missing, why don't you just try to run it ;) I fixed it. Next time please make a **small** example. 6/7 rows maximum would have been enough to make your point.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`packaging.version.Version`](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html#packaging.version.Version) and a reverse [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) to identify the offending version:

```
from packaging.version import Version

s = df['document_section_id'].replace('', None).dropna().apply(Version)
df.loc[s.index[s[::-1].cummin().ne(s)], 'document_section_id'] = ''
```

Output:

```
   document_section_id               
0                    1       Heading1
1                  1.1       Heading2
2                 None   HeadingNoTOC
3                 None   HeadingNoTOC
4                 None   HeadingNoTOC
5                 None   HeadingNoTOC
6                 None   HeadingNoTOC
7                 None    TblFootnote
8                 None   HeadingNoTOC
9                        HeadingNoTOC
10                None   HeadingNoTOC
11                None   HeadingNoTOC
12                None   HeadingNoTOC
13                      ListParagraph
14                None  ListParagraph
15                None  ListParagraph
16                None  ListParagraph
17                None  ListParagraph
18                None  ListParagraph
19                None  ListParagraph
20                None  ListParagraph
21                None  ListParagraph
22                None  ListParagraph
23                None   HeadingNoTOC
24                None   HeadingNoTOC
25                None   HeadingNoTOC
26                None   HeadingNoTOC
27                None   HeadingNoTOC
28                 1.2   HeadingNoTOC
29                None   HeadingNoTOC
30                None       Heading2
31                None   HeadingNoTOC
32                None    TblFootnote
33                None    TblFootnote
34                None    TblFootnote
35                None    TblFootnote
36                 1.3    TblFootnote
37               1.3.1    TblFootnote
38                None       Heading2
39                None   HeadingNoTOC
40               1.3.2       Heading3
41                None   HeadingNoTOC
42                None       Heading3
43                None   HeadingNoTOC
44                None   HeadingNoTOC
45               1.3.3       Heading3
46                None   HeadingNoTOC
47                None       Heading3
48                None    TblFootnote
49               1.3.4       Heading3
50                None       Heading3
51                None       Heading3
52                None       Heading1
```

Intermediates:

```
        s reversed_cummin     !=
0       1               1  False
1     1.1             1.1  False
9       3             1.2   True
13    4.1             1.2   True
28    1.2             1.2  False
36    1.3             1.3  False
37  1.3.1           1.3.1  False
40  1.3.2           1.3.2  False
45  1.3.3           1.3.3  False
49  1.3.4           1.3.4  False
```

Comment: this gives me error: `df=df_combined.copy()
s = df['document_section_id'].replace('', None).dropna().apply(Version)
df.loc[s.index[s[::-1].cummin().ne(s)], 'document_section_id'] = ''` `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 274 but corresponding boolean dimension is 328`

Comment: I don't see how this error is possible. Producing [mre] is critical to efficiently answer questions. The **minimal** part is important. You need to think carefully and craft a meaningful example. Ideally no more than a dozen rows. Can you provide a MRE that reproduces this error? Not sure if I'll have time to answer today, so don't rush, craft a nice **concise** example.

Answer (score 1):

Your updated output looks nothing like the initial one I used when starting at the question. Also your comment *"You can ignore the output. basically 3 and 4.1 needs to be replaced with "" anyway"* adjusts the algorithm accordingly.

I found a solution to your **INITIAL** question and data.
It's definitely not pretty, but works. And since your question and data is changing every 3 minutes, I won't put any more efforts in solving it.
So, maybe this helps you as a starting point.

```
def unique_headings():
    unique_list = []
    for val in PARAGRAPH_TYPE:
        if val not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(val)
    return unique_list


def numeric_vals(_unique_list):
    return {
        val: val.split("Heading")[1]
        for val in _unique_list
        if "Heading" in val and val.split("Heading")[1][0].isnumeric()
    }


def get_idx_of_vals(heading_dict):
    out_dict = heading_dict.copy()

    as_array = np.array(PARAGRAPH_TYPE)
    for key, value in heading_dict.items():
        out_dict[key] = (value, np.where(as_array == key)[0])
    return out_dict

unique_list = unique_headings()
# ['Heading1', 'Heading2', 'HeadingNoTOC', 'TblFootnote', 'ListParagraph', 'Heading3']

num_vals = numeric_vals(unique_list)
# {'Heading1': '1', 'Heading2': '2', 'Heading3': '3'}

with_positions = get_idx_of_vals(num_vals)
# {'Heading1': ('1', array([ 0, 52], dtype=int64)), 'Heading2': ('2', array([ 1, 30, 38], dtype=int64)), 'Heading3': ('3', array([40, 42, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51], dtype=int64))}
```

```
def check_and_map(_df, mapper):
    def apply_check(_ser, _val):
        if (_ser["section"] and _ser["section"] != _val and _ser.name not in mapped_ranges) \
                or _ser["section"] is None:
            out_ser[_ser.name] = ""
        else:
            out_ser[_ser.name] = _ser["section"]

    out_df = _df.copy()
    reverse_ordered = dict(sorted(mapper.items(), key=lambda kv: int(kv[1][0]), reverse=True))
    mapped_ranges = []
    out_ser = _df["section"]
    for value_tuple in reverse_ordered.values():
        val, arr = value_tuple
        min_idx, max_idx = arr.min(), arr.max()
        out_df[min_idx:max_idx + 1].apply(
            lambda x: apply_check(x, val),
            axis=1
        )
        mapped_ranges.extend(list(range(min_idx, max_idx + 1)))
    return out_ser


SECTION_ID_DF = pd.DataFrame(dict(section=SECTION_ID))
mapped_ser = check_and_map(SECTION_ID_DF, with_positions)
print(mapped_ser.to_list())
# ['1', '1.1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3', '', '', '', '4.1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1.3', '1.3.1', '', '', '1.3.2', '', '', '', '', '1.3.3', '', '', '', '1.3.4', '', '']
```

Comment: @xxArbisRox could you please elaborate tye PARAGRAPH_TYPE and SECTION_ID, the above should get Name error.

Comment: @Dcook the initial question raised by the author included these as columns of the DataFrame. So i.e. PARAGRAPH_TYPE represented the list of elements, which is now denoted by `df["PARAGRAPH_TYPE"]` and SECTION_ID represented the list of elements now denoted by `df["SECTION_ID"]`. They are now given with the keys `"document_section_id"` (--> SECTION_ID) and `"'   '"` (--> PARAGRAPH_TYPE) in the input `data` dict by the author.